# Creating table as a body of email

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs3

I am creating a button and onclick of button I able to place `mailto` and `subject`. I want to place html table as a body in email but it getting stuck.

my code is :

```
{
xtype : 'label',
displayLabel:true,
hidden: IsPrevalence,
html : '<a style="color:#000F59;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;"  href="mailto:bob@bob.com?subject=tester&body=<table><tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr></table>">test'/>'+ "Email"+'</a>',
}
```

Thanks for help.